# how arguments are passed to __init__ in classes

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to understand `__init__` in class in Python.I understood how classes work but i could not understand 1 thing
here is code:

```
class Computer:

    def __init__(self, name, cpu, ram, hdd, ssd):
        self.name = name
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram
        self.hdd = hdd
        self.ssd = ssd
    def config(self):
        print("Configuration of computer is: ", self.name, self.cpu, self.ram, self.hdd, self.ssd )


computer1 = Computer("HP ", "i7 ", "16gb ", "1TB ", "256GB")
computer1.config()
```

why and how arguments `Computer("HP ", "i7 ", "16gb ", "1TB ", "256GB")` are passed to `__init__(self, name, cpu, ram, hdd, ssd)` automatically?why we are writing this arguments in class parentheses and not separately like this:

```
 computer1.__init__("HP ", "i7 ", "16gb ", "1TB ", "256GB")
```

how the code can understand  that arguments written in Computer's parentheses have to be passed to `__init__` ?

Comment: It's because that's how Python works - if you use the class name and gives it parameters, those parameters are passed on to `__init__` - what's usually [called a constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) (and Python's `__init__` can be considered one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because The `__init__` method is roughly what represents a constructor in Python. When you call `Computer("HP ","i7 ","16gb ","1TB ","256GB")` Python creates an object for you, and passes it as the first parameter to the `__init__` method. Any additional parameters(more than the five you declared) will also get passed as arguments--in this case causing an exception to be raised, since the constructor isn't expecting them.

Comment: Discussing the "additional parameters" is confusing, because the question and your answer only provide exactly 5.  Makes it hard to parse what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

This is how python works.
Probably it was designed like that because some classes/structures are written in pure C.

For example.
When you want to implement custom class and implement for it `len()` function, so you could get length of it by calling `len(instance_of_your_class)`. Then all what you have to do is implement method `__len__()` in your class.
On the other hand, you have class `list` in python. This class is implement in C, cause it has to be very fast. Then when you call `len(instance_of_list)` interpreted will call `__len__`, which will call equavilent function in C.

From this design comes lot of benefits. One example is method `__getitem__`. You implement so you could be able to get elements with `instalce_of_class[2]`. But it also give you ability to use `in` (`if value in instance_of_class`).

You can read about methods like that. In python jargon they are `dunder` methods.